# create php copys with different variables inside

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in MySQL with info of different places. I want to create a profile page in PHP for each one of those places but there is a lot of them (more than 5000).

So if i do that manually it'll take me a lifetime!. What I did is, created a template that is working just fine (is retrieving the data from the data base perfectly). The only problem is that I want a profile for all of the places and what I have to do now is to copy that template, go inside that copy and change a variable (ID) so it became the profile of another place. Is there any way to do this automatically (create the copy, go inside change the (ID), and save that with another name I.E. `$nombre_lugar`?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your database along with the code that you are currently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the variable inside the page,
set it as a query string

```
yourpage.php?place_id=x
```

and inside your page

```
$place_id = $_GET['place_id'];
```

Comment: Jacob...i just leave my girlfriend to marry you if you want!!! THAAAANKKSSS MAAANNNN!!! you saved me a TON of time...i own you big time man...you have a new friend in Valencia!!!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but i'll pass.  :)
Just mark the question as answered for future reference if you can

Comment: hahahaa your loss man...i have fifa13 on the Xbox and we could have an open marriage but anyway hahahahaa...seriouslly now thanks again i own you big time!

Comment: Not sure my GF will approve such an arrangement :)